# What is better to install 10.04.2 or 10.10 or Debian 6.0.0?

Tags: 10.10, 10.04

I want to install something Debian-based, now I have pre-installed SLED 11 SP1, Laptop HP 4520s.

Answer (score 2):

If you want stability to the point of using somewhat old Linux technology, then Debian is for you - it's virtually bug-free. But if you want to enjoy newer technology with a good guarantee of stability, go for 10.04.

Be warned, if you're opting for Debian, getting latest packages will be no easy feat. Their repo will be full of thoroughly tried and trusted outdated packages, so if you want the latest not-thoroughly tried and tested by Debian, you need to compile and install them by yourself.

Comment: +1 Debian is *very* stable, but due to the testing/stabilizing process, the packages are often outdated (read: missing new features). For a desktop, you should choose for Ubuntu because the packages are more up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with Ubuntu for your user / development environment. Debian makes a better server environment. I'm guessing 10.04 is more stable than 10.10 because it a Long Term Support (LTS) release.

Answer (score 0):

there is no point in installing debian 6.0 for desktop usage.
You should install Ubuntu 10.10 according to be since you are a desktop user(it is more refined and user-friendly).

For HP DriveGuard You Have to Download the appropriate deb and install it.

[Maverick (32-BIT)](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa/+files/hpfall_2.6.35-0pmjdebruijn1%7Emaverick_i386.deb)
[Maverick (64-BIT)](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa/+files/hpfall_2.6.35-0pmjdebruijn1%7Emaverick_amd64.deb)

[Lucid (32-BIT)](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa/+files/hpfall_2.6.32-0pmjdebruijn2%7Elucid_i386.deb)
[Lucid (64-BIT)](https://launchpad.net/~pmjdebruijn/+archive/ppa/+files/hpfall_2.6.32-0pmjdebruijn2%7Elucid_amd64.deb)

Comment: I've noticed that SLED 11 SP1 has some features i've never seen in 10.10, for instance, HP DriveGuard. To be precise, I need Stability just to work on my lappy. Is 10.10 okay?

Comment: Yes 10.10 is stable and also hp driveguard can work in ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In one equation: **Ubuntu = features with inherited stability from Debian / Debian = stability with features added from Ubuntu**

My personal habits are:

- my laptop: Debian `testing` (wheezy, "7.0.0") with `unstable` (sid) [under-pined](http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html), I administer my laptop on a day to day basis and I prefer to read a few changelog a day than a massive amount two times a year.
- other's personal computer: Ubuntu, unattended security update (Windows-like) and when needed backup+upgrade
- servers: Debian stable (squeeze, 6.0.0), never dist-upgrade.

Why I don't use an Ubuntu LTS over a Debian stable? Compare yourself:

- Debian stable:

  - packages: 6 month maturing from Debian testing (short definition of testing is unstable without more bug)
  - new features: 6-24 month maturing
  - less community
- Ubuntu LTS

  - packages: 6 month maturing from Debian unstable (all bug welcome)
  - new features: 6 month maturing
  - more community

Comment: That is a very interesting system you're using. However, it would need considerable skill and experience to manage them, selectively choosing packages, from here and there, etc. Not a solution for people who just wants to use their computers out-of-the-box.